# Best way to write pojos that can have common fields

Tags: java, pojo

I am currently making a service in which there are lots of public API's. And the response and request objects overlap a lot. So, I was thinking that is there a way by which we can generalise the pojo creation for the request/response objects.
Sometimes the response object is identical to the request object with one or two extra fields.

Let me give you an example.

```
@Data
public class Request {
    private A objA;
    private B objB;
}

@Data
public class Response {
    private A objA;
    private B objB;
    private C objC;
}

@Data
public class A {
    private D objD;
}

@Data
public class B {
    private String sB; 
    private E obje;
}

@Data
public class C {
    private String sC;
}
```

---

Similary, D and E are pojos as well. The thing is that there is a lot of similarity(overlapping fields) in request/response objects.

Comment: Create a common class that will be extended by `Request` and `Response`. Add all common fields to this class and mark them as `protected`? I am not sure where the complexity is in this question.

Comment: Make use of an `abstract class` and then place the common fields in there

Comment: Your problem does not show they need to define a common base Type that is going to be used by the application as well as the need for Template method pattern that requires parent class. Just because many classes share the same fields does not mean they need to be bound together by inheritance. I would much rather just keep them separate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution is probably inheritance: Create a parent abstract object type with the overlapping fields and have the request and response objects extend it and specify any extra (unique) fields they need.

**Inheritence**

```
public abstract class Common {
  private String overlapfield1;
  private String overlapfield2
}

public class Request extends Common {
  private String requestField1;
  private String requestField2;
}

public class Response extends Common {
  private String responseField1;
  private String responseField2;
}
```

You could also approach this using composition:  Create an object type with the overlapping fields and include this object as a sub-object of the Request/Response types:

**Composition**

```
public class Common {
  private String overlapfield1;
  private String overlapfield2
}

public class Request {
  private String requestField1;
  private String requestField2;
  private Common common;
}

public class Response {
  private String responseField1;
  private String responseField2;
  private Common common;
}
```

There are pros and cons to each approach which are widely discussed on this and other boards.  These however, are the two standard approaches to dealing with such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. I don't see it being a huge problem repeating the fields but you've given an abstract use case rather than a real world situation where I can understand what you're trying to achieve.

Perhaps you want to pass your @Data objects to the same services? In which case you might want to use interfaces because a class can implement multiple interfaces.

Eg

```
public interface AContiner {
    A getA();
    void setA(A a);
}

public interface BContiner {
    B getB();
    void setB(B b);
}

@Data
public class Bean1 implements AContainer {
    private A a;
}

@Data
public class Bean2 implements AContainer, BContainer {
    private A a;
    private B b;
}

public class MyFantasticService {
    public void doStuffWithA(AContainer data) {
        System.out.println(data.getA());
    }
    public void doStuffWithB(BContainer data) {
        System.out.println(data.getB());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this solves his issue.  The Request and Response objects will still have to specify lots of duplicate fields, whether or not they contain the method declarations for acting on those.

Comment: I'm not sure he's explained his issue well. See my updated comment